# Parsing protocol parameter (URL) in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch, protocol-handler

I'm trying to use a .bat file as a protocol handler. The protocol URL for example is `testapp://close` and I set the protocol to launch `"C:\test.bat" "%1"` in the registry.

The `test.bat` file

```
@echo off
echo %1
pause
exit 0
```

Essentially what I want to do is just pass the parameter in the URL `close` to some application to execute `C:/someapp.exe close` however the `%1` parameter I get is the full url `testapp://close/`. How can I parse the `close` parameter out of the `%1` variable using only native Windows commands?

Comment: Try this: `explorer.exe testapp://close`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`FOR /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop and with the options `"TOKENS=2 DELIMS=/"` you can get the value from the URL string passed in as the first argument at batch script execution ***after its (the URL value) second forward slash (`/`) but before the next forward slash (`/`)*** giving you the expected result exactly as you describe you need from that part of the URL.

You can `SET` the parsed URL string as a variable value and use that to pass as the first argument to the application executable file. I'll put a couple batch script examples below to help further clarify.

---

### #1. Batch Script

```
@echo off
echo %~1
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ("%~1") DO (SET "var=%%~A")
echo %var%
pause
exit 0
```

### #2. Batch Script

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ("%~1") DO (CALL C:/someapp.exe "%%~A")
EXIT 0
```

---

### #1. Correlated Output Results

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop> test.bat "testapp://close/"
testapp://close/
close
Press any key to continue . . .
```

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- **`FOR /?`**

  > ```
  >     delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
  >                       default delimiter set of space and tab.
  >     tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
  >                       be passed to the for body for each iteration.
  >                       This will cause additional variable names to
  >                       be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
  >                       specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
  >                       the last character in the tokens= string is an
  >                       asterisk, then an additional variable is
  >                       allocated and receives the remaining text on
  >                       the line after the last token parsed.
  > ```

Comment: @Matt For **#2 Batch Script** you might consider using `FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ("%~1") DO (START "" C:/someapp.exe "%%~A")` to use start in place of call but I suspect you already know this but wanted to mention in a comment just in case.